# Bug with the opening of an iOS project

Tags: ios, splash-screen

I'm developing an iOS application using Objective-C. I have created a splash screen view controller in Storyboard, in which I need to run some code. The problem is that when I launch the app, before the splash screen shows; I get something like in the picture below:

**When I launch the app**

[image]

I think it's a navigation controller. Here is my code for the .m file of the splash screen controller:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;

    self.progressView = [[ICDMaterialActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height -150, 100, 100) activityIndicatorStyle:ICDMaterialActivityIndicatorViewStyleLarge];
    [self.progressView startAnimating];
    [self.progressView setColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    self.progressView.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, self.view.bounds.size.height -155);
    [self.view addSubview:self.progressView];

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [self performSelector:@selector(loadingNextView)
               withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0f];
```

Any ideas how to remove this first screen so I can show the splash as the first one ?

Comment: Your image link doesn't work for me.

Comment: Before your app launches it will show the launch image or a scene from a launch storyboard.  Have you set something for one of these?